# discord.js Manager was destroyed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im trying to start up my discord bot but i keep getting this error i can't figure out how to fix it and nothing online is pointing in any directions for me any help would be appreciated

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const path = require('path');
const oneLine = require('common-tags').oneLine;

const client = new commando.Client({
    owner: '184191493919997952',
    commandPrefix: '>',
    invite: 'https://discord.gg/YB8fmw#'
});

client.login('token num').token;


Registered group basic.
Registered argument type string.
Registered argument type integer.
Registered argument type float.
Registered argument type boolean.
Registered argument type user.
Registered argument type member.
Registered argument type role.
Registered argument type channel.
Registered argument type message.
Registered argument type command.
Registered argument type group.
Registered group commands.
Registered group util.
Registered command util:help.
Registered command util:prefix.
Registered command util:ping.
Registered command util:eval.
Registered command commands:groups.
Registered argument type group|command.
Registered command commands:enable.
Registered command commands:disable.
Registered command commands:reload.
Registered command commands:load.
Registered command commands:unload.
Registered argument type dank.
Registered command basic:roll.
Preparing to connect to the gateway...
[WS => Manager] Manager was destroyed. Called by:
Error: MANAGER_DESTROYED
    at WebSocketManager.destroy (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:335:54)
    at CommandoClient.destroy (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:235:13)
    at CommandoClient.destroy (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\client.js:174:15)
    at CommandoClient.login (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:224:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:21856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:135:26)
    at CommandoClient.login (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:221:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21856) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

code above errors below.
cant appear to find a fix so im guessing i broke something :P but visual studio isnt reporting problems in files listed as causes.

Comment: Could you post the code related to this error?

Comment: That looks like your client login() call failed: that's what prints "Preparing to connect to the gateway", and destroys the web socket manager on failure. Do you really not get any more errors after that? It ought to give you details of the login failure.

Comment: updated sorry guys thought it pasted okay

Comment: OK the bit you need to solve is: "Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided." Where did you get the token from? Can you try generating a new one?

Comment: i did try that it didn't like it either

Comment: ```const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const path = require('path');
const oneLine = require('common-tags').oneLine;

const client = new commando.Client({
 owner: '184191493919997952',
 commandPrefix: '>',
 invite: 'https://discord.gg/YB8fmw#'
});

client.login('toke num').token;```

Comment: give it a go now

Answer (score 1):

Fixed after many token regens it finally accepted a token I would like to thank Rup for the help.